# Is it possible to get the object name passed into a function as a variable from within the function

Tags: javascript, function

As per the title is it possible to retrieve a variable name from within a function.

For example i am passing a selector object into a function

```
get SAMPLE_ELEMENT () { return $('h2=example') }
```

This is passed into a function

```
verifyElementTextTranslated (element)
```

What i would like to get back is `SAMPLE_ELEMENT` as this will be used to compare against a json file to extract the correct translation.

I've tried element.toString() but that gives me an `[object, object]` back, trying just to return `element` gives me the entire object back obviously.

Not sure if it is actually possible because if my understanding is correct as variable names aren't passed into the function?

Thank you

Comment: It is not possible.  (What if the value passed isn't in a variable?)  What problem are you trying to solve that (seems to) require this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean? As in pass the selector string and don't store it in a variable?

Comment: I'm saying it is possible to pass a value that is not stored in a variable, in which case there is no name to be gotten.

Comment: yeah obviously, but thats not how my framework is setup. Which is why i was exploring the more complicated method. But thank you for reviewing, appreciate your time and the confirmation that what i want isn't feasible!

Comment: `SAMPLE_ELEMENT` is a property name (in particular, of a getter property), not a variable name. Are you doing `const element = something.SAMPLE_ELEMENT;` somewhere? Please give more context!

Comment: In my function i want to get `const elementName = element.toString()` or something equivalent to that

Comment: You can pass the name as its own parameter. `verifyElementTextTranslated(parent, propertyName) { var element = parent[propertyName]; /* now you have the element and its property name */ }`

Comment: In the example above what would be the parent and what would be the property name?